# Field length overflow in Netty SSL

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, netty, tls1.2

I use Netty to implement a server with secure socket. My code of sslHandler is:

```
SslHandler sslHandler = SslContextBuilder
                            .forServer(certFile, keyFile)
                            .trustManager(trustFile)
                            .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)
                            .build()
                            .newHandler(channel.alloc());
```

`trustFile` is a File object which contains around 700 pieces of certificate text, like:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEHDCCAwSgAwIBAgIJAOR6+3G8C6f7MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGNMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJVUzESMBAGA1UECAwJQ2FsaWZvbWlhMRwwGgYDVQQKDBNDaXNjbyBTeXN0
................................................................
igHdyc519KbYSMfhuM9gXw35LPmFWStBGYikBcMZJ1WmWxb/eZOK1SMjVQ/L/JVg
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

When I connect the server with

`curl -k -v -E client.pem --key client.key.pem --cacert rootCA.pem https://10.140.28.33:31069`

an exception pops up:

```
11:00:18.636 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] WARN io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Field length overflow, the field length (106142) should be less than 65536
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Field length overflow, the field length (106142) should be less than 65536
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1476)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:255)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1162)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1084)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Field length overflow, the field length (106142) should be less than 65536
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.checkOverflow(HandshakeOutStream.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.putInt16(HandshakeOutStream.java:163)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateRequest.send(HandshakeMessage.java:1442)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage.write(HandshakeMessage.java:143)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:971)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:224)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1301)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1214)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

**But if I trim the trust file with only a few certificates left, no error happen.**

Is it a JDK bug? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Please, can you show the code you used to trim the trust file?

Comment: @Jamin, I just delete a lot of certificates text to make the trust file smaller.

Comment: Why do you need 700 trusted certificates?

Comment: @EJP, because I need client authentication, and there is more than 1000 clients which is slef-signed.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong technology, because you're breaking this one. You should use a single trusted signer. One certificate to trust instead of > 1000.

Comment: I agree with EJP you should probably think about using a different methodology for handling all your certificates.

Comment: @EJP, yes, I think you are right. Using trusted CA maybe the best practice.

Comment: And don't conflate authentication with authorization. You need to build the authorization step into your application, *based on* the identity established by the certificate. Merely relying on the security provided by a text file isn't secure, and it isn't the purpose of PKI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be a bug that JSSE doesn't give a clearer alert, but there is a fundamental problem.

When an SSL/TLS server requests client authentication, it normally sends a list of the certificate authorities the client should use in the Certificate Request message, see [rfc5246 7.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4) or earlier. Since you trust a huge number of selfsigned certs, where each selfsigner effectively acts as a CA for itself, this means **your server needs to send a huge list of CAs** -- but this list is limited to 65535 bytes total. Your exception shows you are trying to send 106142 bytes **which doesn't fit** in 65535 bytes; this means your cert names (Subjects) average about 150 bytes, which seems to me a bit on the high side if these are used entirely within your enterprise and thus presumably don't need globally unique names like the public web (especially EV with its enhanced identity requirements).

One possible workaround, if all your clients know which cert to use without being prompted, is for the server to send the CA list as empty, which is permitted though not encouraged. JSSE simply populates CertReq.CAlist from the trustmanager's `getAcceptedIssuers()` method, and the TrustManager API is designed for customization, so you could just wrap the real X509TrustManager with one that validates the received cert chain normally, but returns `getAcceptedIssuers()` as an empty array. This is fairly easy with the actual Java classes (`SSLContext` et amici) but I'm not sure exactly where to look in Netty's 'improvements'.

But a better solution, as noted in comments by EJP, is not to individually trust a huge number of selfsigned certs but instead have a CA issue the client certs and then the server need only trust that CA (and transitively the certs it issues) and CertReq automatically specifies only that CA. If you don't already have a suitable established CA to use, there are many options to do your own CA, discussed in other Qs here and other Stacks (IME mostly security.SX unix.SX and serverfault), but given you are using Java remember that since j7 `keytool -gencert` does a minimal but usable CA function. (In addition to keypair and CSR generation which `keytool` has done back to the dark ages.)